# Predicate to use Find on a List of Tuple

Tags: vb.net, list, find, predicate

I have this `Dictionary`:

```
Public TblDic As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Tuple(Of Date, Date, Decimal)))
```

I need to retrieve the 3rd item (Decimal) of the Tuple having the highest date on 2nd item.

I was able to retrieve the 3rd item by knowing the date but I wasn't able to retrieve the highest date:

```
Dim LastDate As Date = Date.ParseExact("31/12/2016", "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                       New CultureInfo("it-IT"), DateTimeStyles.None)
Dim LastRate2 As Decimal = TblDic("Legali").Find(Function(D) D.Item2 = LastDate).Item3
```

Another way could be to put all tuple into a DataTable and use DataTable.Select to retrieve the decimal field this way:

```
Dim LastRate As Decimal = DT_Rates.Select("EndDate=MAX(EndDate)")(0).Field(Of Decimal)("Rate")
```

So, my questions are:
1) is it possible to use List.Find without knowing the last date?
2) what is the best practice between List.Find and DataTable.Select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use Find... maybe? But I think this is simple enough without it.

```
Dim LastRate As Decimal = TblDic.
    SelectMany(Function(k) k.Value).
    OrderByDescending(Function(k) k.Item2).
    First().Item3
```

`SelectMany()` takes many sequences and flattens them into one sequence. The sequences in this case are values of the dictionary, `List(Of Tuple(Of Date, Date, Decimal))`

`OrderByDescending()` orders the flattened sequence by the predicate, which returns the `Date` of the `Tuple(Of Date, Date, Decimal)`. This orders *all* the `Tuple(Of Date, Date, Decimal)` across all the lists since they were flattened

`First()` takes the first `Tuple(Of Date, Date, Decimal)` after it was ordered by the date descending

`Item3` returns the `Decimal` of the `Tuple(Of Date, Date, Decimal)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have some questions for you: Have you considered that, if I use `Find`, I can avoid to populate a `DataTable`? and: is it possible to use directly `TblDic.OrderByDescending`? (I tried but without success).

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with a DataTable; it's pure LINQ on generic collections. If you order the dictionary, you will still just have a dictionary of lists. Though there are roundabout ways to achieve your desired result by doing that, anything I can think of would be more complicated than my answer. Did you try my answer, and if so, did it work?

Comment: You're rigfh! It was my misunderstanding reading your code. Thanks again